# Extract multiple strings from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a description field where data is going to look like this:

```
ID     Description                                   Title
1234   serial numbers are *XC54566, AB2345fg, 12IUT456*  blahblah
```

I want to extract everything inside the two asterisk and show them in a column with ',' being the delimiter that differentiates between the serial numbers. The output would then look like

```
ID    Serial_Numbers
1234  XC54566
1234  AB2345fg
1234  12IUT456
```

Looking for a SQL Server query to extract this information using SELECT and some form of substring/left/right function thingy.

Hopefully a SQL select statement.

Comment: Are there any reliable markers for where the serial numbers start and end? Is it always and exactly `serial numbers are *` followed by `* blah blah blah`? Are the `*` even in the data? Do the serial numbers fit a specific pattern? Or are you expecting natural language processing to infer what is a serial and what is not? (Either way, this type of parsing is MUCH better suited to other languages than SQL; Process it BEFORE it reaches your database.)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

If sequence does not matter, how about a `string_split()` or two ?

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Serial_Numbers = trim(C.value)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply String_split([Description],'*') B
 Cross Apply String_split(B.Value,',') C
 Where B.Value  like '%,%'
```

**Results**

```
ID      Serial_Numbers
1234    XC54566
1234    AB2345fg
1234    12IUT456
```

Comment: This might fail if the string contains commas outside of the asterisk separated space

Comment: Will also fail to identify lists of just one element (no comma).

Answer (score 0):

at the first  I Use XML For retrieve the 2nd element then in the second step, to separate with , from STRING_SPLIT.
yo can use this Query:

```
select ID,trim(Value) 
from(
    SELECT ID,CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(Description , '*','</t><t>') + '</t>' AS 
    XML).value('/t[2]','varchar(50)') as A
    FROM T
   ) as B
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(A,',')
```

I used the following table and data for testing

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Description]) 
VALUES (1234, N'serial numbers are *XC54566, AB2345fg, 12IUT456*')
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Description]) 
VALUES (5678, N'serial numbers , are *XC54566, AB2345fg, 12IUT456*')
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Description]) 
VALUES (9784, N'serial numbers are *XC54566*')
```

Answer (score 0):

//select * from dbo.search('XC54566, AB2345fg, 12IUT456')

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1
    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))
        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End
    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))
    Return
END
```